# SwiftUI Video Player autorotation issue

Tags: ios, swiftui, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am embedding SwiftUI `VideoPlayer` in a `VStack` and see that the screen goes black (i.e. the content disappears even though video player gets autorotated) when the device is rotated. The issue happens even when I use `AVPlayerViewController` (as `UIViewControllerRepresentable`). Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

```
var videoURL:URL
let player = AVPlayer()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
                        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
                        .frame(height:300)
                        .padding()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .background {
                            Color.black
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            player.rate = player.rate == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0
                        } 
       
        Spacer()
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .background(content: {
        Color.black
    })
    .onAppear {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.duckOthers)
        } catch {
            NSLog("Unable to set session category to playback")
        }
        
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    }

 }
```

Comment: `let player = AVPlayer()` is a potential issue -- that means the `player` will get reloaded with every re-evaluation of the view hierarchy.

Comment: I made player as a State variable and the problem disappeared!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring `let player = AVPlayer()` as a property on the `View` like this, the `player` will be recreated every time the `View` is re-evaluated. You should store the player somewhere persistent (a `@State` or `@StateObject`-based solution).